# Mysql SELECT and UNION multiple tables with a similar name

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to create a dynamic Union query for all tables with the same name but with a different number at the end. I have created a system but with each user having their own table such as:

> user_table_$userID

I have achieved this in PHP but really would like to create a more dynamic code. I currently have 2-3 nested queries to grab the posts from each table without putting strain on the web server or database.

I suppose I could count the number of users in the user login table and create a for loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i >= $usrCount; $i++)
{
    $queryArray[] = "(SELECT post_title, post_description FROM user_table_" . $i . ") UNION";
}
```

But if the user count is a very large number the PHP script could take a long time to load. Is there any way I could get the Mysql database to create a dynamic query based on tables with the name like = "user_table_%"

If there are any suggestions please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all it seems like unnormal database schema to create table for each user

Comment: I think the obvious suggestion would be to normalise your schema so you don't have a table for every user in  your system.

Comment: try stored procedure also performance get improve

Comment: A table for each user sounds like madness to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and even if you find a clever hack you shouldn't.

Your best bet is to think again about your database schema. I assure you that your current structure is BAD, very very BAD. What if by chance you develop the new facebook? will you have ONE BILLION TABLES?

search for google about "database normalization" and "3rd normal form"

Comment: I have a better idea. Because posts will be dealt with by category I suppose I could just make tables based on category and UNION those instead.

Comment: sure, the point of this answer is to make you rethink your database schema. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to normalize your database, but if you need a dynamic query you could use this:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT * FROM `',
      TABLE_NAME,
      '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
WHERE
  `TABLE_NAME` REGEXP '^user\_[0-9]*$'
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e92c/3).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should have only one table `user_table` containing a `user_id` field.

Now if you still want to keep your current model and need MySQL to build your query, maybe you could:

```sql
SHOW TABLES LIKE "user_table_%";
```

Create a temporary table and do `INSERT SELECT` for each table.

But again, it's barely advised to say the least

Answer (score 0):

First normalized your table,for the time being you can run this query

SELECT post_title, post_description FROM (select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA where table_name like 'user_table_%';

Comment: I'm going with STT LCU with this one because handling hundreds of tables is a bad idea.#

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine (but consider "database normalization")

```
for ($i = 1; $i >= $usrCount; $i++){
  $queryArray[$i] = "(SELECT post_title, post_description FROM user_table_".$i.")";
}    
$sql = implode(' UNION ', $queryArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic queries are called Views in MySQL. These are virtual tables that contain the results from querying other tables and are persisted so survive a restart of the server. Here is an example of creating a view that contains the posts from all users:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_users.posts AS
SELECT * FROM user1.posts
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM user2.posts;
```

Learn more here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html