# Union all with loop in oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working in an oracle DB that has 20 tables with the same structure but divided by years. So, it started in ft_expenses_2002 and goes until ft_expenses_2021 (the year when I'm writing this). I need to put all these tables' columns together before doing some maths and my first approach was to use UNIAN ALL statements. It worked but I'm wondering if it's possible to do something more elegant, like using a FOR LOOP. It would not only make the query far more elegant but would avoid future maintenances because every year a new table with the "_new_year" suffix will be created.

Comment: More elegant would be storing the data in a single table, with a column for the year.

Comment: Totally agree, but this is an old DB and I started work with it recently. So, unfortunately, there is no way to change this now.

Comment: If there's someone elegant, who adds new table every year instead of redesign, then this someone can elegantly add this table to the view with `union all` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057977/11755155) a really good and short way to solve my problem, it was:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT * FROM `',
      TABLE_NAME,
      '`') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
WHERE
  `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'ft_expenses_%'
INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view for all the tables:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ft_expenses AS
          SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2002
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2003
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2004
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2005
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2006
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2007
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2008
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2009
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2010
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2011
-- ...
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ft_expenses_2021
```

Then just do your query using the view.

Next year when you add a 2022 table then recreate the view with the extra table added to the view.

---

Alternatively, create a table from the originals so that everything is in one table that you can query directly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ft_expenses (year, col1, col2, col3) AS
          SELECT 2002, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2002
UNION ALL SELECT 2003, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2003
UNION ALL SELECT 2004, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2004
UNION ALL SELECT 2005, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2005
UNION ALL SELECT 2006, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2006
UNION ALL SELECT 2007, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2007
UNION ALL SELECT 2008, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2008
-- ...
UNION ALL SELECT 2021, col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses_2021
```

Then drop the individual tables (make sure you backed everything up first) and create views if you still need to access then by the original names:

```
CREATE VIEW ft_expenses_2002 (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses WHERE year = 2002;

CREATE VIEW ft_expenses_2003 (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses WHERE year = 2003;

-- ...

CREATE VIEW ft_expenses_2021 (col1, col2, col3) AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ft_expenses WHERE year = 2021;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of "elegant".

It's certainly possible to use dynamic SQL to look for every table whose name fits a particular pattern.  My guess is that the simplest thing to do would be to create a view that does the `union all`, write your processing code against that view, and then have a bit of dynamic SQL that can rebuild the view based on what tables exist.  You could then run that procedure when new tables are created (if you can hook in to that process) or based on a DDL trigger or just schedule it to run in the early morning hours every year/ month/ day depending on how likely it is that a new table is going to suddenly show up.

```
create or replace procedure build_view
as
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(32000);
  type typ_table_names is table of varchar2(256);
  l_tables typ_table_names;
begin
  l_sql_stmt := 'create or replace view my_view as ';

  select table_name
    bulk collect into l_tables
    from user_tables
   where table_name like 'ft_expenses%';

  for i in 1 .. l_tables.count
  loop
    l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt || 
                    ' select * from ' || l_tables(i);
    if( i != 1_tables.count )
    then
      l_sql_stmt := l_sql_stmt ||
                      ' union all ';
    end if;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line( l_sql_stmt );
  execute immediate l_sql_stmt;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You physical setup of the tables is *state of the art* of Oracle 6 (late 1980's).

You have two possibilities to *upgrade*. Either the `DIY` *union all* view as proposed in other answers, or simple follow the development the Oracle implemented since the above mentioned version.

*Note*, I'd **not recommend** to follow the advise to *put all data in one table* - why? You'd see no difference in the queries covering all data, but you'll spot a significant *decrease in performance* in queries on one or few years.

What was done in Oracle on this topic since the release 6?

In Oracle 7 (1990's) a [*partitioned views*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A48506/partview.htm) was introduced - which is similar idea to the proposal of the `UNION ALL` view.

Starting with Oracle 8 **partitioning** concept was introduced any improved in each following release.

So if you want to leverage the current Oracle features the *partitioning* should be applied:

- managing the data in acceptable size
- providing a flexibility in the access

Here an example how could you *migrate* in Oracle 19c

*I assume that you table contains a column `trans_dt` containing a `DATE` with a year same as the tables year*.

Start with the oldest table and **change it to a partitioned table**

```
alter table ft_expenses_2002 modify
  partition by range(trans_dt) interval(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'YEAR'))
  ( partition p_init values less than (DATE'2002-01-01')
  ) online
```

**Rename the table eliminating the year**

```
rename ft_expenses_2002 to ft_expenses;
```

Now the table in *partitioned* and contains two partitions, the *initial* one and the partition for the 2002 year.

```
select PARTITION_NAME from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'FT_EXPENSES' order by PARTITION_POSITION;

PARTITION_NAME                                                                                                                  
---------------- 
P_INIT
SYS_P2340
```

For each following years perform the below steps

**Add a new partition**

```
alter table ft_expenses 
  exchange partition for( DATE'2003-01-01' ) with table ft_expenses_2003
```

Note that you use the `for` syntax to address the partition, so there is no need to know the partition name.

Additionally the recent version can *create the partition* in the exchange statement, so there is no need to [`lock table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-9A05E5AB-3A08-4502-A25B-4246E26CA2C0.htm) anymore.

**Final Notes**

You may include indexes in the reorganization.

As always backup all tables before  start.

Test carefully to check possible limitations.